# Link HTML file with CSS file in Visual Studio

Tags: html, css

Im a beginner in Visual Studio and my html file/code work fine but my css file doesn't work. My problem is not detected in the workspace.

I also try to do this, nothing happen :

```
<link href= "CSS\index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

CSS code :

```
style
h1 {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also new but I think I can help. You have two options, that I am aware of.

The first and ideal option would be to reference to a separate style.css file to go along side your maim html page (ex: index.html & style.css).

(index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>yourwebsite.com</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <img src="your.jpg" alt="Handsome Man" width="100" 
height="100">
    
        <h1><b>your name</b></h1>
    
        <p>your tag line</p>
    
        <a href="https://twitter.com/yourtwitter"</a>
    </body>

</html>
```

(styles.css)

```
body{
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    color: #555555;

    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;

    /* Same as above */
    /* font: normal 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; */

    line-height: 1.6em;
}

h1{
    color: #00ff00;
}

p{
    color: rgb(0,0,255);
}
```

The second and worst option is to include your css within your main html file.

```
(Copied from https://ryanstutorials.net/css-tutorial/css- 
including.php)

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Embedded CSS example</title>
<meta name="description" content="A page with embedded css">
<meta name="keywords" content="html css embedded">
<style>
h1 {
text-decoration: underline;
color: #4583c2;
}
p {
padding-left: 20px;
font-size: 18px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well your code work, maybe the meta tag that make confusion, i honsetly don't know.
But thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the index.css file is inside the CSS folder, then add the below link tag.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./CSS/index.css">
```